# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter/material.dart'

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication

I've just set up my Windows 11 for Flutter development,

So I updated flutter SDK, and placed it in my Documents. After, I got this:

```
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter/material.dart'.
The function 'runApp' isn't defined.
Classes can only extend other classes.
The name 'WidgetBuilder' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
Undefined class 'Widget'.
Undefined class 'BuildContext'.
The method 'MaterialApp' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'.
The method 'ThemeData' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'.
Undefined name 'Colors'.
The method doesn't override an inherited method.
```

What is an error? It's difficult to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command in terminal:

```
flutter pub get
```